# Ruby Hash Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a YAML file:

```
0:
  price: 0
  storage: 8
  instances: 1
  hours: 2
1:
  price: 9.99
  storage: 8
  instances: 2
  hours: 25
```

I'm attempting to select all paid plans only as such:

```
@plans = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/plans.yml")
@paid_plans = @plans.select {|plan| plan[1]['price'] > 0}
```

But it says

```
no implicit conversion of string into integer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

YAML values are just strings so `plan[1]['price']` returns `'9.99'`, so I think you will need to convert the value to a numeric type before doing the comparison. e.g. `plan[1]['price'].to_f > 0`.

Comment: when I try to reproduce this, I get: `plans[1]['price'].class
=> Float` using ruby 2.0.0 with psych 2.0.6, which confuses me to no end, since I thought I would obtain a string.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me; the error remains. I think the issue is in the hash part, not the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was related to the structure of the select; it takes a key/value pair. It should have been:

```
@plans.select {|k,v| v['price']>0}
```

Answer (score 1):

`0:`, `1:` and so on can be strings. Either use [YAML lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Lists) or search for a string key:

```
plan['1']['price']
```

Also note that your select doesn't make much sense anyway, as it will always check the N1 plan.

Comment: ya, and even name it 0: and 1: is bad approaching. we just troubled there in rails.

Comment: @cjm2671, what do you mean? `plan['1']['price']` outside of the `select` fails?

Comment: No, it actually works even without the plan[1]['price'] outside the select. I tried it in an each and it works just fine; seems the select breaks it.

Comment: @cjm2671, could you add the `each` that you used and what was it's output so it will be easier to reason about the `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Its a string not a float/int/number. You need to cast it. And why not using I18n enginge?